# scenario for recursive trigger

Tags: trigger

Can any one out here give me a scenario for recursive trigger. Why don't we able to control the trigger in the same place. Why do we go for a class under every trigger Context. Please provide me a scenario where recursive trigger occur.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting, in 'after update' trigger, Developer is performing update operation and this lead to recursive call. i.e. the trigger will fire again

Comment: I need to know how a recursive occur with a scenario. Why do we need a separate class  to handle the recursive trigger why can't we use the same trigger to code and manage. I want to learn by scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How it occurs:** 
Consider an "after update" trigger on Opportunity. Inside the trigger, if you attempt to update the triggering object(the trigger context opportunity), you know that this new `update` action also tend to fire the "after update" trigger again. This is endless recursive and salesforce doesn't allow this situation(which doesn't need to allow).

```
trigger updateTrigger on opportunity(after update) {

    List<Opportunity> updatingList = new List<Opportunity>();
   for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
        o.someField = someValue;
        updatingList.add(o);
   }
   update updatingList;  //this will perform an update on the triggering object and this trigger will fire again and again
}
```

**How to resolve**
I haven't think about any other way to resolve this than having a static boolean flag as a switch. In the trigger context we can update a status of a boolean flag to make sure the trigger to be fired only once as below.

```
public Class checkRecursive{
    private static boolean run = true;
    public static boolean runOnce(){
        if(run){
          run=false;
          return true;
       }else{
        return run;
    }
}
}
```

Trigger code :

```
trigger updateTrigger on Opportunity(after update) {

    if(checkRecursive.runOnce())
    {
        //your logic here           
    }
}
```

**Note** : You need to make sure that the trigger need to be fired only once if you are doing this. Best thing is to reduce the `update` DMLs on same object inside the trigger. Or set the required population on triggering object in a "before update" trigger if possible.

**Update** : 
Depend on the requirement and context we may use different triggers. Context variables considerations can be found in [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm) and can get some idea. Also [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) is the trigger context variable list.

Salesforce doesn't recommend to have multiple triggers on same object and same event(before update, after update, etc.) since they can't guaranteed  which will fire first. But according to the requirement, and the availability of fields at the context, we have to use several triggers. It's no matter since those are on different events.

e.x. You can't have Id of the object in a "before insert" trigger. If you need to track the Id of the triggering object you need to have an "after insert" trigger.

Read about the [order of execution](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) as well.

Comment: thanks can you tell me why do we need different different triggers on a same object why don't we have everything in a single trigger. can you please give me a scenario for this issue.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider this scenario:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update, after update) {
   if(Trigger.isBefore) {
        // do something
   }

    if(Trigger.isAfter) {
        List<Account> accounts = [select Custom_Field__c from Account Where Id IN :Trigger.new];
        for(Account account : accounts) {
            account.Custom_Field__c = 'value';
        }
        // this causes a recursive update, because you're updating Account from within the Account trigger
        update accounts;
    }
}
```

To avoid the scenario above, people tend to utilise an additional class to store a static variable which can be referenced from within the execution context of the Trigger firing.  For example:

public class AccountTriggerHandler {
    public static Boolean fire = true;
}

Then, they would reference that variable within their code to prevent the recursion happening, e.g.:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update, after update) {
   if(!AccountTriggerHandler.fire) return;

   if(Trigger.isBefore) {
        // do something
   }

    if(Trigger.isAfter) {
        // prevent trigger from firing again after we update Account from within this trigger
        AccountTriggerHandler.fire = false;
        List<Account> accounts = [select Custom_Field__c from Account Where Id IN :Trigger.new];
        for(Account account : accounts) {
            account.Custom_Field__c = 'value';
        }
        // this causes a recursive update, because you're updating Account from within the Account trigger
        update accounts;
    }
}
```

This is quite a crude example, but hopefully illustrates the point to you. You can't create the 'fire' static variable within the body of the trigger itself because you simply can't declare a public static variable within the body of the trigger. Some Trigger frameworks will help you with this kind of thing.

Comment: cant we compare old map with new.trigger value to stop recursive. Then we can avoid the static class.

Comment: I guess it depends on your specific case...you might be able to, do you have some objection to using a static variable? - its a simple solution that is fairly ubiquitous

Comment: I can't see why you wouldn't want to use the static to avoid this. You can as you say do the comparison but if there is workflow or something else in your system that also changes account values then you could risk the recursive loop situation. The static as suggested above will work no matter the scenario.